# PHP SimpleXML Optional Child Nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to separate my child nodes according their children but I can't figure out how to validate whether the node has a value.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testcase>
 <steps>
 <step id="one">
    <command>gettitle</command>
 </step>
 <step id="two">
    <command>click</command>
    <parameter>id=searchByAddressSubmit</parameter>
 </step>
 </steps>
</testcase>
```

Here's my Code:

```
$testcase = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($testcase->steps->step as $step) {
    echo $step->parameter;
    echo $step->command;    
    if(empty($step->parameter)) {
        echo $step>command;
    }
}
```

The result should be:

```
gettitle
```

I've tried empty(), array_key_exists(), and is_null() but nothing seems to pick a missing value. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is indeed a typo and you are not getting any output, it just means you have an error on this line:

```
echo $step>command;
```

It should be `->`.

If you have turned on error reporting, it should have given an error message:

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant command - assumed 'command' in

This should be:

```
// turn on error reporting on development
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$testcase = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($testcase->steps->step as $step) {   
    if(empty($step->parameter)) {
        echo $step->command; // fixed arrow operator
    }
}
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OJocwe)

Comment: Thanks! Always with the typos.